# How to Implement Full page Scroll?what is my mistake?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Two different Activities for Single Purpose(first activity one Contains Elements like Buttons, Spinners... and second activity contains results of the Activity). In my Activity, I've to display the Huge Amount of data, so I prefer using TableLayout. Everything looks Good. But Now I want to Display the Hidden Data, so I've used ScrollView(Vertical). Without ScrollView all the data is displayed perfectly, but at the bottom of the Screen, I get to see only Two lines (When i scroll, i get to see all data, but the display portion is small) so i decided to use full screen scroll but now only first data is displayed and rest isn't shown.

This is snapshots [image: myactivity(activity1 and activity 2)]
before filter this is my output

if i want to filter by staff so i choose staff and press load button then i get this out put [image: OUTPUT]

this the problem i get lot of results but only one (first result ) is displayed. scroll not working

Activity 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#282828"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#282828"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="PRODUCTION PENDING REPORT"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </TableRow>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/type_a"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="DATE"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/type_b"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:text="STAFF"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/type_c"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:text="MIN NO WISE"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RadioGroup>

            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/datepicker_btn"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="FROM DATE"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/datepicker_btn"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="TO DATE"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDate2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/loadbtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btnbg"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="LOAD"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_customername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@null" />
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity :2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#282828"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#282828"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Production_no"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="S.NO"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/S_No"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="ORDER NO"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="STAFF NAME"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/staffname"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="ORDER DATE"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/order_qty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="MIN NO"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/min_no"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="ORDER NO"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/In_qty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="MIN DATE"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/created_date"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="PRODUCT"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/created_date1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="PRODUCT"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/out_qty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="ORDED QTY"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/qty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/balan_qty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="FIN QTY"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Finish_qty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/row_border"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="BALANCE QTY"
                    android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/balance_qty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where you have used Scrollview?

Comment: Please add ScrollView in xml layout files.
Also provide screen shot of your activity

Comment: yes thats the problem. when i place Scrolview in my first activity sec activity scroll not working @shahzainali

Comment: The layout of your first activity should not affect the second activity.

Comment: if i place Scrollview as parent layout/ place between linear and table layouts nothing changes

Comment: place in both, these activities are not connected, it is impossible that placing in one activity stops the other one @karthiWenture

Comment: i put scrollview in both activities but same result some contents are not displayed @shahzainali

Comment: which activity you want to scroll first or 2nd

Comment: both , because Elements are in 1st activity and the result displayed in sec activity so at a time i displayed both activities. my result is huge so i want to scroll full page. thats why i use scrollview in both activites @VV

Comment: for checking purpose only: remove scroll view, then just scroll the bottom part only this is working r8? only the list view

Comment: Correct bro when i remove all scrollviews, the result only scroll perfectly but above the element part fixed

Comment: scroll and list view won't work together

Comment: then there is no solution right?

Comment: I can suggest one thing ; is that ok to show the result in separate activity, just list view only

Comment: no bro its not our project you know above that clients? i hope u genius and get experience

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118385/discussion-between-v-v-and-karthiventure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This Code

**You Create Custom ListView Which is non Scrollable**

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();    
}
}
```

**Activity 1 :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#282828"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#282828"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="PRODUCTION PENDING REPORT"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </TableRow>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/radioType"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/type_a"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:text="DATE"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/type_b"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                            android:text="STAFF"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/type_c"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                            android:text="MIN NO WISE"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </RadioGroup>

                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="FROM DATE"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="TO DATE"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvDate2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="1dp"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="1dp"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="2dp">


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/loadbtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="LOAD"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>

            <NonScrollListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_customername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@null" />
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**- If you set data on list view then its scroll. It will not scroll because of no data in listview.**

Comment: you add data in listview or not

Comment: yes i can add and also add data using my sec activity (textviews)

Comment: Second activity use as a custom raw for listview ?

Comment: in sec activity there is no list view

Comment: sec activity is costume raw or activity. Means sec activity you use in listview of 1st activity ? You known costume listview ?

Comment: yes bro i can use my sec as a listview to display data

Comment: hey bro you can use dynamic list view instead of list view.

Comment: how can i use that bro ?

Comment: after create that??

Comment: You create NonScrollListView  file ?

Comment: ok after that NonScrollListView add in XML file in Activity 1 file instead of Listview.

Comment: Just add this

<NonScrollListView
                android:id="@+id/listview_customername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null" />

Comment: i am geting this error :  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vari.new_varri/com.example.vari.new_varri.Production_Pending}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #228: Binary XML file line #228: Error inflating class NonScrollListView

Comment: pls msg me skype : tejas.prajapati26

Comment: can you give me path where you have create NonScrollListView.class file

Comment: New_Varri/app/src/main/java/com/example/vari/new_varri/NonScrollView.java

Comment: <com.example.vari.pratipal.new_varri.NonScrollListView
                android:id="@+id/listview_customername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null" />

In Class File
------------------
NonScrollListView listview_customername= (NonScrollListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_customername);


You have add your full path in xml file and also change class file like create NonScrollListView object instead of Listview object above. Check and reply me.

Comment: Look at my above comment i have set your path.

Comment: i made chages in xml but class i am confusued bro

Comment: listView1 as my object and i have a doubt we change the listview into NonScrollListView so there is no listview in my xml. then how can you use listview?

Comment: You have create object like
ListView listView1;

change by

NonScrollListView listView1 ;

Comment: You have create object of  NonScrollListView not ListView.

Comment: in my main java file ?? or NonScrollListView java file ? thats my confusion

Comment: Main java File bro.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118409/discussion-between-karthiventure-and-tejas-prajapati).

Answer (score 2):

**Activity2.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#282828"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#282828"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Production_no"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="S.NO"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/S_No"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="ORDER NO"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/product"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="STAFF NAME"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/staffname"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="ORDER DATE"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/order_qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="MIN NO"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/min_no"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="ORDER NO"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/In_qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="MIN DATE"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/created_date"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="PRODUCT"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/created_date1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="PRODUCT"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/product_name"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/out_qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="ORDED QTY"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/balan_qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="FIN QTY"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Finish_qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="BALANCE QTY"
                        android:textColor="#FF00B0FF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/balance_qty"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                        android:textColor="#00aa55"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />
                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Nothing Affected, i can also change both activities as scrollview as parent layout no success

Comment: in the first activity, there is a list view at the bottom. why you add scroll view with a list view. which will not work

Comment: when i give scrolview to listview it not scroll full page right?@VV

Comment: yes. never use a list view inside scroll. it is not a good practice

Comment: i add my screen shots @VV

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you can't use listview and scroll view at the same time. if you what you both at the same time. you need to create a custom list view  try something like this instead of your list view

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {
public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
    params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
}
}
```